# MultipleSelect input value field in MUI DataGrid Filter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Anyone know how to do a multiSelect value for MUI DataGrid filter value.
Currently I'm using singleSelect but I need to be able to pass it a mulitSelect but not sure how to do this ?

```
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        field: "col1",
        headerName: "Name",
        sortable: false,
      },
      {
        field: "col2",
        headerName: "Options",
        sortable: false,
        type: "singleSelect",
        valueOptions: [{value: 'one', label: 'Option1'}, {value: 'two', label: 'Option2'}],
      },
    ],
  );
```